# integrate FancyFileUpload with python3 flask

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, google-cloud-storage

The main problem: how to integrate Fancy Responsive File Uploader For jQuery with python3 flask.

I want to use Fancy Responsive File Uploader For jQuery - FancyFileUpload with python3 flask, I was following this [tutorial](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Fancy-File-Uploader-jQuery.html), but I got confused when implementing it to python3 flask

The HTML File:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancy_fileupload.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fancy-fileupload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/final" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="demo" type="file" name="files" accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png">
</form>
    <script>
    $('#demo').FancyFileUpload({
      params : {
        action :'fileuploader'
      },
      maxfilesize : 1000000,
      // send data to this URL
      'url' :'/upload'
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

The python3 flask file:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
   return render_template('page.html')
@app.route('/upload')
    def upload():
       # what should I code here?
       # I want to upload the image to google cloud storage and get the public URL
       URLFile = upload_image_to_GCS("bucket_name", "/tmp/image1.png", "/file/image1.png")
@app.route('/final')
    def upload():
       # what should I code here?
       # I want to get the public URL uploaded image from '/upload' and save it to the database
       uploadToDatabase("https://storage.google.com/bucket_name/file/image1.png")
       # redirect to "/"

def upload_image_to_GCS(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    blob.make_public()

    return f"{blob.public_url}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

I am just confused about integrating flask and FancyFileUpload and how to handle the uploaded file? And where do I save and find the uploaded file? And how to integrate it with the database postgresql. please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if this answers your question? [Upload an object to a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object)

Comment: thanks, but The main problem: how to integrate Fancy Responsive File Uploader For jQuery with python3 flask.

for the GCS it was solved in upload_image_to_GCS function